# Windows Store: "Something wrong happened on our end"

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

Every time I am trying to install a new app on Windows Store I am getting the message box: Try again. Something happened at our end!

I've looked at different solutions and tried:

- scan check (100% healthy)
- reset the windows store
- reinstall windows store (from add/remove components)

Nothing seems to work. I have a quite fresh copy of Windows and the only suspect that I can connect to this event is that I removed all the crappy pre-installed apps (using [Debloater](https://github.com/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater)).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Debloater is known for damaging things beyond repair. My brother for example uninstalled cortana and can't use his startmenu anymore, so he's forced to use an alternative shell. If you have a fresh copy of Windows, I recommend a reinstall.

Comment: Looks like it. Actually, I just opted in for the Windows Insiders `dev`-branch and after a long 'update/installation' this problem was fixed. Would be nice to know what caused it though.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot help you determining probable causes. We're a Q and A kind of site, and if the problem no longer exists, we cannot determine if it was the solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

Debloater is known for damaging things beyond repair. My brother for example uninstalled cortana and can't use his startmenu anymore, so he's forced to use an alternative shell. If you have a fresh copy of Windows, I recommend a reinstall.

You mentioned you did an upgrade to an insider build, which basically is a reinstall.

Comment: You can seamlessly go from Semi-Annual to Insider Preview builds.  However, only 19H2 and 20H1 are being offered in the Fast and Slow channels with 19H1 is in the Release Preview channel.